# UICollectionView Data not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: MaterialCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MaterialCollectionViewCell
    let item = items()[indexPath.item]
    //print(cell.contentView.subviews)
    for view in cell.contentView.subviews{
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    //print(cell.contentView.subviews)
    let colors = [UIColor.grayColor(), UIColor.darkGrayColor()]
    cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item % 2]

    let showTitle: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))
    showTitle.text = item.title
    showTitle.textAlignment = .Center
    showTitle.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 25.0)
    showTitle.textColor = MaterialColor.white
    showTitle.center = cell.center
    showTitle.hidden = true
    //print(showTitle.text)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(showTitle)


    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))
    imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: item.banner)!,
                                 placeholderImage: nil,
                                 optionsInfo: nil,
                                 progressBlock: { (receivedSize, totalSize) -> () in
                                    //print("Download Progress: \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
        },
                                 completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
                                    //print("Downloaded and set!")
                                    if (image != nil) {
                                        showTitle.removeFromSuperview()
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        showTitle.hidden = false
                                    }
        }
    )
    cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    //print(cell.contentView.subviews)
    return cell
}
```

this is the code I am using to display data into show title label. For the moment imageView doesn't ever show
issue with mine is the complete data is not displayed instead a part of it

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi1sn.png)

Should have shown these in the same order

- Game of Thrones
- Orange Is the New Black
- Marco Polo (2014)
- Person of Interest
- Dark Matter

Comment: maybe the inconsistency caused by the adding and removing subviews in cellForItemAtIndexPath. the cell item is reusable view. Have you using label or image in storyboard instead of programmatically?

Comment: no the complete code is programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the UILabel view and the UIImageView are overlapped 。 You should shrink the size of UILabel, and put the UIImageView behind the UILabel.

Comment: I removed the image view still the issue persists